# Vim method to jump to number under the cursor

Tags: vim, vim-macros

In vim, is there a more elegant way to jump to a line number under the cursor than

```
map gn "nyw@nG
```

"gn" or some other key combo? This necessitates ensuring the cursor is at the beginning of the string of numbers. Also, this macro COULD be a bit hazardous depending on what's in register "n".

Not entirely sure even why this works: `@n` means to execute what's in register n (a number), not concatenate it with the "G".

Functions with something like

```
call cursor(expand("<cword>"),1)
```

don't seem to work either.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend this:

```
nnoremap gn yiw:exec (@" =~ '^\d\+$' ? 'norm @"G' : '')<cr>
```

It fixes a lot of the problems you have mentioned, for example:

- > this necessitates ensuring the cursor is at the beginning of the word ("word" here means string of numbers).

  Using `yiw` instead of `yw` fixes this problem. Read up on [text objects](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/10/17/vim-text-objects-the-definitive-guide/)!
- > also, this macro COULD be a bit hazardous depending on what's in register "n".

  This will only execute any code if your cursor is over a number. Otherwise it does nothing.

There are also some other advantages:

- Using `nnoremap` instead of `map` is the best practice. It will save you a lot of headaches down the road! ([more info](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2089/2920))
- It doesn't mess with your `@n` register.

> not entirely sure even why this works: @n means to execute what's in register n (a number), not concatenate it with the "G".

Typing `@n` inserts the text inside the register n into the typeahead buffer, exactly as if you had typed it. So if a command is unfinished, it will sit there (as if you had typed it) waiting for the command to finish. You could even run a macro like

```
3d
```

which will sit there waiting for a motion, before deleting three of those motions.

Comment: expertly done, explained.  an important distinction (for me at least) is the how the command is interpreted wrt @n is not "execute n", it's a modifier being held in a "command line" (for lack of a better term) until the line is complete with the motion. this is perfectly clear now.